# Variable (suddenly) becomes None after referencing outside while loop. Sockets in Python 3

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am trying to make two simple functions that use sockets and act as a server/client for sending some text.

I can send text and print it out but when I store it in a variable and try to access it **outside** the `while` loop **which it was created in**, the variable becomes `None`.

Here is my (full, because it's really small) code:

send.py (the client):

```
import socket   
def send(HOST2 = "localhost", PORT2 = 50007,):
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s2.connect((HOST2, PORT2))
    s2.sendall(b"Hello, world!")
    s2.close()
send()
```

The code above works as expected.

recive.py (the server):

```
import socket
def recive(HOST = "localhost", PORT = 50007):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        global data
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode("ascii") 
        print(data) #This will print correctly as expected
        if not data: break
    conn.close()
recive()
print(data) #This is None
```

My question is how to use the variable data outside the loop. For some reason it is None. My guess is that it has to do something with local/global variables or it is the way socket module behaves.

**EDIT:** I have changed the code and the problem is still there.
Changes: Added `recive()` and `send()` calls.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to write `global data` if it wasn't declared globally. Either make an actual global variable before the function is called or better yet don't use global variables at all and return data from your receive function.

Comment: I don't want to return anything because when the function is called it will wait indefinetly and if it get's no input the program might stop.

EDIT: Also could you explain what do you mean by "actual global variable"? To declare a variable outside any functions?

Comment: Yes, actually declare it outside the function. e.g. `data = -1`. But your justification for not returning it isn't making any sense.

Comment: Okay. Returning will return None and if I declare it outside the result is exactly the same :/ Python bug?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you expect to be printed from the `print` call outside the function. Your condition for `break`ing out of the loop in the function is that `data` be "falsey", so you're probably printing an empty string.

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry for waiting so long. Anyways if not data: break exits the loop if data is not empty, so when the data is recived, it breaks the loop. This correctly works. I can print, modify, anything you can do with a variable INSIDE the loop, but if I try to do anything OUTSIDE the loop it will say that it's defined as b"" (empty binary string), unlike inside the loop where the same variable worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, well, the "outside the loop" code runs after the loops ends, so it will see the last, empty value. If you want to see the previous values, you need to store them somewhere they won't be overwritten by the next `recv`, such as in a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is not only outside the loop, it is outside the function. It will be executed before the function is even called, and has no access to the data variable within the function.

Indent it one more level so it is within the function.

Comment: this will, of course, not help since the loop will break when `not data` evaluates to true.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The loop will break when data is an empty string, at which point it will not be None.

Comment: *OP* is implying that he would like to access the data read, or at least that is my interpretation of what he's asking - I could be wrong though (hence why I did not downvote).

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

Firstly it's generally convention to declare your globals at the top of a function, not partway through

Secondly, is there more to your code? because from what you posted you're defining a function and then trying to access a global which would be set by it without actually calling it.

Update:

I ran your updated code and it worked fine for me

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 50007))
>>> s.sendall('test')
>>>


pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python recive.py
test
```

Update #2:

I'm guessing that your socket is blocking; meaning for the typical case it will wait for some data to return before it returns, which means it won't ever be False when you try to break.  This means that your while loop will never terminate and the second print will not execute.  To test this theory throw a break after the first print and before the `if not data: break`

Comment: "test" is supposed to be printed twice. Once inside the while loop (what you see on the screen) and once more outside the function (which did not print).

Comment: Specner Sorry for waiting so long. Wasn't really active on StackOverflow. Anyways the loop does end. My problem is that I can't acess the variable data OUTSIDE the while loop after it's broken. However I can use the variable data no problem INSIDE the loop. What is really weird is that when I acess it outside the loop it doesn't say it's not defined (so it was defined correctly), it says the varaible is set to b"". An empty binary string. So I know it is defined correctly, just don't know why it doesn't keep the text inside it.

Comment: Lets take a step back and look at what's going on here.  You're trying to access the variable data outside of the loop you have defined.  The condition on the loop is `True` which means that it will only ever exit if you break. The only condition that you break on is `if not data`. Assuming data is a string, this will only ever be False (and hence true when negated) if it is the empty string.  Therefore it is only logical that if you try to access it outside the loop that it will be the empty string, as if it were not you could not possibly be outside the loop.  Does that make sense?